# Why doesn't my container show in the live server?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am doing an example of flexbox for class but the container part of my CSS does not show when I look at the page through Live Server.

I tried defining container in my HTML portion but that put it either above or below my example boxes.[screenshot of code and live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcz27.png)[picture of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkkwn.png)

Comment: Could you please post your HTML code?

Comment: Is it this only in this version you posted or you are not using the container class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container doesn't show because you forgot using the css class in your html.

Try this html code here into your body:

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container{
  border: 20px slid green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.red, .yellow, .blue{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
 }
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
 }
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container box">
  <div class="red">
    red box
  </div>
  <div class="yellow">
    yellow box
  </div>
  <div class="blue">
    blue box
  </div>
</div>
```